# How to use XML wrapped in CDATA inside another XML for XSL transformation?

Tags: xslt, xslt-1.0, cdata

An XML document contains another XML element, which is wrapped in CDATA.

How can the wrapped XML be used for XSL and XSL-FO transformation (version 1)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is not possible with standard XSLT 1.0 or 2.0, in a single transformation.

It can be done using Saxon 9 Professional Edition or Enterprise Edition. These products have a [`saxon:parse()`](http://www.saxonica.com/documentation/functions/saxon/parse.html) extension function. Or use the [XPath 3.0](http://www.w3.org/TR/xpath-30/) [`parse-xml()`](http://www.saxonica.com/documentation/functions/fn/parse-xml.html) function, which is also supported by recent versions of Saxon PE/EE.

---

As @grtjn points out, it is possible to do it with a two-pass process. Stylesheet 1 turns the CDATA-wrapped text into parseable XML (using `<xsl:value-of select="whatever" disable-output-escaping="yes"/>`). Stylesheet 2 then processes the serialized result produced by stylesheet 1.

Comment: It should be possible in a second pass, as  already pointed out by [@grtjn](http://stackoverflow.com/a/9108085/413020). Shouldn't it?

Comment: Keep in mind that it can make difference how the two process steps are tied together. I have seen situations in which two XSLT steps were connected in Java through SAX events, but it turned out that the unescaping was being delayed until the serialize, so subsequent XSLT's couldn't access the unescaped XML..

Comment: @grtjn: Yes, the result tree must be serialized for `disable-output-escaping="yes"` to work.

Answer (score 2):

If you are willing to take multiple transformation steps then it is possible. Output the relevant section with disable-output-escaping to turn the escaped XML into valid XML. Process it in a subsequent step.

It does require the escaped XML to be well-formed. And some parsers require the intermediate result to be serialized (to disk or else) first to make sure the escaped XML is properly unescaped before it enters the subsequent transformations.