# How to retrievea particular tag value from the cdata section using xsl

Tags: java, xml, xslt, jaxb, cdata

My XML is like bellow

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<Students>
<![CDATA[<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?> <Student><rno>1</rno><name>xyz</name>     </student>]]>
</Students>
```

with the help of XSL i want to retrieve the value of rno which is present inside cdata section. How I can read this value

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to use XML wrapped in CDATA inside another XML for XSL transformation?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9093934/how-to-use-xml-wrapped-in-cdata-inside-another-xml-for-xsl-transformation)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First of all, in your xml you should replace `</student>` by `</Student>` .
Because XML tags are case sensitive [reference here](http://www.w3schools.com/xml/xml_syntax.asp).

The trick to do that on your own is the following :

```
public static String getRNO(){

    String valueRetrieved = null;

    DocumentBuilderFactory dbf = DocumentBuilderFactory.newInstance();
    DocumentBuilder db = null;
    Document doc = null;

    try {
        db = dbf.newDocumentBuilder();
        doc = db.parse(new File("D:\\Loic_Workspace\\Test2\\res\\test.xml"));
        NodeList ndList = doc.getElementsByTagName("Students");
        String xmlRetrieved = ndList.item(0).getTextContent();

        if(xmlRetrieved != null) {
            //CALL OF STRING REPLACE METHOD TO PREVENT FROM
            //at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.parsers.DOMParser.parse(Unknown Source)
            //at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.jaxp.DocumentBuilderImpl.parse(Unknown Source
            xmlRetrieved = xmlRetrieved.replace("<?xml version=\"1.0\" encoding=\"UTF-8\"?>", "");

            doc = db.parse(new InputSource(new StringReader(xmlRetrieved)));
            valueRetrieved = doc.getElementsByTagName("rno").item(0).getTextContent();
        }


    } catch (ParserConfigurationException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (SAXException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    }


    return valueRetrieved;

}
```

Hope it helps ;-)